# error variable in Zend_View (ZF1)

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have a new project to inspect and manage. It is written with ZF1.

There are views, contained in .phtml files which contain following code:

```
echo $this->partial('error.phtml', array('error'=>$this->error));
```

My issue is that no business logic, controller code or other application code sets
that error variable explicitly. I am hunting it down and need to figure out if this 
error is set by Zend Framework itself.

My main lead is the CallbackHandler.php in Stdlib folder. It seems to be responsible for setting
an error flag to true, when its errorHandler is executed. Problem is that I'm not sure.

My second guess is that it is dead code and if $this->error is simply not used anywhere.

Any guesses ?

Comment: Where is this code found ? `echo $this->partial('error.phtml', array('error'=>$this->error));` A layout? View? ...

Comment: What does `$this->error` look like if your `print_r` it? Does it look like something coming from Zend or something custom made?

Comment: @php-dev It is a .phtml view file. Object $this is an instance of Zend_View.

Comment: @alex It is NULL. Where it could possibly be set is actually my question.

Answer (score 0):

It depens on kind of displayed error.
For system errors write something like ErrorController and redirect to error page after handling of exeption(in dev mode you can add displaying of stack traces, etc).
For form validation "errors" there is build-in instruments to display it in forms.